# SLA COUNT IN EXCEL FORMULA

Tags: excel

I'm looking for an excel (Office 2016 packet) formula that count SLA for ticket resolution.
the SLA counter must consider  :

1) **Monday** To **Saturday** as work day ;
2) Holiday as no working days (must be skipeed as work day);
3) SLA  start for ticket generate in workdays during range-time "**08:00-20:00**" out of this time-range SLA count is "0" ;
4) Output should result as **R1**= first 24Hours ; **R2**= from 25 to 48 hours ; **R3**= from 49 to 72 hours; "**Out of Sla**" = since 72 hours

Data to count SLA is formatted as below for either for ticket open and closure:
**Column N                 Column O           Column P      Column Q**
**"TICKET START DATE"   "TICKET STOP DATE"     "SLA"        "HOLIDAY"**
   28/4/18 13:30           30/4/18 19:20         2          25/04/2018
   28/4/18 13:11           29/4/18 13:11         1          01/05/2018
   28/4/18 12:57           28/4/18 12:57         1

I solved  point 1) & 2) with **NETWORKDAYS.INTL** formula using the first column as **start_date** ; the second column  as **end_date**; **11** as third formula's field to exclude Sunday as workdays; fourth formula's value pointing a column where are listed the "**holidays**" date .
I could not find a solution for point 3).
It will also appreciate a possible solution for point 4) .
Thank you in advance.
Formula example of above fields :

=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(N15;O15;11;Q16:Q17)

Alessandro.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal,  Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: Hi Thank you first of all .
I modified it as below :

=IFERROR((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(N15;O15;11;Q16:Q17)-1)*("20:00"-"8:00")+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(O15;O15;;);MEDIAN(MOD(O15;1);"8:00";"20:00");"20:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(N15;N15;;)*MOD(N15;1);"8:00";"20:00");"")

but as you say the result is a medium of time worked not exactly wat I need according to point 4) as result and also if I modified date to check how formula work I got an unexpected result (for instance in third line "1 hour"  even if passed more then 24 hours as SLA)

Comment: TICKET START DATE TICKET STOP DATE SLA HOLIDAY TEST SUGGESTED
28/4/18 13:30 30/4/18 19:20 2 25/04/2018 23:20
28/4/18 13:11 29/4/18 13:11 1 01/05/2018 12:00
28/4/18 12:57 2/5/18 9:00 3  1,04

Answer (score 0):

I've needed to do something similar in the past. Please see the formula below. It will give you the amount of time between working days (Monday-Friday), only taking into account times 8:30am to 5:30pm. Try inserting your specific parameters.

```
=IFERROR((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H8,I8,,)-1)*("17:30"-"8:30")
+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(I8,I8,,),MEDIAN(MOD(I8,1),"8:30","17:30")
,"17:30")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(H8,H8,,)*MOD(H8,1),"8:30","17:30"),"")


H8 = Start Date
I8 = End Date
8:30 = Start Time
17:30 = End Time
```

Comment: Hi Mario I tried the solution but unfortunately it didn't work . I used as start "line with parameter like "1/6/18 18.49" and as stop "5/6/18 18.49" and the output is "1" . I also populate "NETWORKDAYS.INTL" parameters "Start date";"Stop date";"11";"List of public holiday" in your example is indicated just the  first 2 field. Sincerely it's no clear to me the "MEDIAN" & "MOD" part. Btw thank you for your feed-back it's already a start. Ciao

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I just tried it out with your specified dates and I got: 31.875. I believe the issue is that you're excel is formatted from a different country. In my formula, it assumes month/day/year. If it is day/month/year, I also end up  with "1".

Comment: Also, my "NETWORKDAYS.INTL" formula works fine. even without the last two fields. The last two fields are "weekend" and "holidays". If "weekend" is left blank, it assumes Saturday & Sunday. "Holidays" is an optional field that can be linked to a list.

Comment: Hi Mario, no way even if I tried (just for a test)to move the field format from Italian to English (USA) choosing date format "Month/Day/Year" output is always "1" . the complete formula used my self  is:"=IFERROR((NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2;B2;11;C$2)-1)*("20:00"-"8:00")+IF(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2;B2;11;C2);MEDIAN(MOD(B2;1);"08:00";"20:00");"20:00")-MEDIAN(NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A2;A2;11;C2)*MOD(A2;1);"8:00";"20:00");"")" . In "NETWORKDAYS.INTL" I need to specify year holidays and Saturday as workday, btw according to the excel formula it is no influence the output. Btw thank you I'm appreciating your help.

Comment: Using your exact same formula, I am getting an output of 51.049. So I think the formula is working fine, I continue to believe it is something with the date format. Try posting a new question, with this formula and ask why it isn't working for you, but it is for me. I'm glad to help!